# "Heightmap" of the PolygonZ features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, 3d-model, building-heights

Let's say I have 3D model of city made from multiPolygonZ features and I need to create black and white image, where each pixel brightness represents height of the building at that coordinate. I need to create pictures like this:

[image]

It is similar to LiDAR scans of cities, but in this case I need to 'scan' the 3D model.

I am architect working with Rhinoceros 3d and there it is very easy to project points to 3D model, but it would be much better to do it in QGIS. But I am not able to find any good solution to this problem.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Just to make it a bit clearer I should say that **the goal is to get heights (z coordinates) of polygonZ at specific points on its surface** (in my case 1x1m grid). It can be also imagined as intersection of vertical lines from point grid and roofs of polygonZ buildings.

I tried Rasterize (vector to raster) but that gives each polygon one colour and that is not what i need - flat roof should be one colour but polygon of gable roof should be gradient (as on picture). Then I tried TIN interpolation which seems better but it is not the result I need either. Finally I tried to somehow in Python where I wanted to move point grid that it would sit on the roof 3d dimensionally, but I have not been able to do it yet. Only points which would si on polygons are created by Centriods or Points along geometry.

Comment: You had a tag for Python but do not present any code so I removed it.

Comment: What have you already tried? Including a few details of unsatisfactory attempts in your question could either lead to suggestions on improving your workflow, or prevent people spending time suggesting a solution you are not satisfied with.

Comment: What about rasterize? In the rest, I agree with @Matt that you should add additional details to make it clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I will try to explain what I tried. At first, I tried Rasterize (vector to raster) but that gives each polygon one colour and that is not what i need - flat roof should be one colour but polygon of gable roof should be gradient (as on picture). Then I tried TIN interpolation which seems better but it is not the result I need either. Finally I tried to somehow in Python where I wanted to move point grid that it would sit on the roof 3d dimensionally,but I have not been able to do it yet. Only points which would si on polygons are created by Centriods or Points along geometry

Comment: @matt Maybe just to make it a bit clearer I should say that the goal is to get height (z coordination) of polygonZ at specific points (in my case 1x1m grid). It can be also imagined as intersection of vertical lines from point grid and roofs of polygonZ buildings.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: Flat roofs or slanted? I.e. is there one height value per building or gradients?

Comment: @bugmenot123 gradient. The roofs have slopes.